# How to intercept methods calling?

Tags: php

i'm creating a user panel, and i want to allow methods depending on the user state, if is logged on or isn't, wich method is called by the url, for example:

```
funciton home () {...}
function create_account () {...}
```

the create_account method is only available if the user's off, and the home when he is on, what i'm doing individually is something like this:

```
function home () {
if(!$userLogged)
die('Ei, little satan, you can't enter here!');
}
```

How can i intercept all methods that have been called and make some rules?

```
    function __interceptAll($method) {
    $userOff = array('create_account'...);
    $userOn = array('home','change'...);

    if(in_array)....
}
```

Comment: You can't intercept methods like that. You could use the `__call` magic method that is called when a method doesn't exist to call a different private/similar method. But you would still need some sort of naming convention or list to identify which functions need login or not. Would still probably be easier to just check in each function.

Comment: You should not try to get the language calling conventions to implement your application logic.  If you want an account creation to check if the user is "off" and produce an error if it is, put that check in the `create_account()` function.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Ugh, don't point him at `__call`.  :)   That's like giving a hand cannon to a new carpenter who just asked how he can blast nails out of a board with explosives...

Comment: @NGTHM4R# why don't use an if condition to call methods depending on  user state

Comment: really, the logic should just be outside of the class. The class should be as dumb as possible and not need to know about stuff that it won't affect. You could put whatever logic you wanted in your `intercept` method outside of the class to determine whether or not a method should be called. You could even make that a function that accepts a callback for pass/fail that is called if the user is logged in or not. Said callback can call whatever method you want.